# ViewPager size does not adapt to current page size

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I've got a ScrollView containing several elements among which there is a ViewPager. I would like my ViewPager height to be the same as its current page heigth (and to be scrollable), to avoid white space at its bottom. 
My ViewPager class is the following

```
    public class ScrollableViewPager extends ViewPager {

        private int currentPageNumber;
        private int pageCount;

        public ScrollableViewPager(Context context) {
            super(context);
            prepareUI();
        }
    public ScrollableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        prepareUI();
    }

    private void prepareUI() {
        setOffscreenPageLimit(pageCount);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int height = 0;
        if (getChildCount() != 0) {
            View child = getChildAt(currentPageNumber);
            child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            height = child.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

I thought it would do the job but with that code my ViewPager as always the heigth of its first page and this no matter what I set as offscreen page limit.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with this.

Comment: Cant you just put a ScrollView inside a ViewPager in your layout.

Comment: I have a ViewPager inside a ScrollView, I want the scroll to be on the whole page, not only on the view pager.

Comment: Where do you set your class fields?